# An independent variable in the logistic regression has 2.2%, 2.1% and 95.7% distribution

Tags: regression, logistic, multiple-regression, predictor

I have one independent variable in the logistic regression with a 2.2%, 2.1% and 95.7% distribution (three categories IV). My DV has good distribution (68% and 32%). How would this IV affect my logistic regression analysis? What should I be cautious about when interpreting the results?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can think of any type of regression as comparing groups. In case of your logistic regression you compare the odds of success for group 1 with the reference category and group 2 with the reference category. So you need to be able to estimate the odds of success in each of the three groups in order to compare them. If some of these groups contain few observations, then those estimates will be uncertain. As a consequence the comparisons (odds ratios) will also be uncertain. You will see that by the large standard errors and wide confidence intervals.